# unknown top level operator: $eq

Tags: database, mongodb, mongodb-query, mongodb-shell

Sample of my database:

```js
{
  name: 'The Perks of Being a Wallflower'
  genres: ['Drama', 'Romance']
  rating: 8
}, 
{
  name: 'The Edge of Seventeen'
  genres: ['Drama', 'Comedy']
  rating: 7.3
},
{
  name: 'Little Women',
  genres: ['Drama', 'Romance']
  rating: 7.8
}
```

I want to project the first element of the genres array if it's `Comedy` *or* `Romance`.
I tried this :

```js
db.shows.find(
  {},
  { genres: { $elemMatch: { $or: [{ $eq: 'Drama' }, {$eq: 'Comedy'}] } } }
);
```

But it gives me this error "unknown top level operator: $eq".

Comment: Apparently `$eq` operator cannot be used in a _projection_ as you are using it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use [$in](https://docs.mongodb.com/manual/reference/operator/query/in/)

> The $in operator selects the documents where the value of a field equals any value in the specified array. To specify an $in expression, use the following prototype:

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/MAuWUeP9GIE

```
db.collection.find({
  genres: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "$in": [ "Drama", "Comedy" ]
    }
  }
})
```

---

Demo - https://mongoplayground.net/p/JJJkoHuz_DZ

```
db.collection.find({},
{
  genres: {
    $elemMatch: {
      "$in": [ "Drama", "Comedy" ]
    }
  }
})
```